# How to update ObservableList in TableView to write to DB?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

When my database information is imported into the `TableView`, everything displays correctly but is not editable and I cannot figure out what is causing this. Can anyone spot the problem?

```
@FXML
public TableView<Clients> activeclients;

@FXML
public void databaseConnection(ActionEvent event) {
    Connection c = null;

    ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try {
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db/clients.db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened Database Successfully");
        String SQL = "SELECT * from clientstest";

        //ResultSet
        ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

        /**
         * ********************************
         * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY *
         * ********************************
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;

            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));

            col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Clients>forTableColumn());

            col.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
                ObservableList row = e.getRowValue();
                row.set(j, e.getNewValue());
            });

            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {

                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });
            col.setMinWidth(175);

            activeclients.getColumns().addAll(col);
            System.out.println("Column [" + i + "] ");
            col.setEditable(true);
            activeclients.setEditable(true);
        }

        /**
         * ******************************
         * Data added to ObservableList * 
         * ******************************
         */
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added " + row);
            data.add(row);

        }

        // Finally Added to TableView  
        activeclients.setItems(data);
        activeclients.setEditable(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

***`Clients` class***

```
package mach1jedi.model;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Clients {

    private SimpleStringProperty fname;
    private SimpleStringProperty lname;
    private SimpleStringProperty clientID;
    private SimpleStringProperty provcontractnum;
    private SimpleStringProperty adscode;
    private SimpleStringProperty transcode;
    private SimpleStringProperty ccucontractnum;

    public SimpleStringProperty getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getClientID() {
        return clientID;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getProvcontractnum() {
        return provcontractnum;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getAdscode() {
        return adscode;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getTranscode() {
        return transcode;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getCcucontractnum() {
        return ccucontractnum;
    }

    public void setFname(SimpleStringProperty fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public void setLname(SimpleStringProperty lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public void setClientID(SimpleStringProperty clientID) {
        this.clientID = clientID;
    }

    public void setProvcontractnum(SimpleStringProperty provcontractnum) {
        this.provcontractnum = provcontractnum;
    }

    public void setAdscode(SimpleStringProperty adscode) {
        this.adscode = adscode;
    }

    public void setTranscode(SimpleStringProperty transcode) {
        this.transcode = transcode;
    }

    public void setCcucontractnum(SimpleStringProperty ccucontractnum) {
        this.ccucontractnum = ccucontractnum;
    }


}
```

Comment: Is your View contains more than one table?

Comment: yea, the Table is in a tabpane and the second tab has a table as well, posting FxML now, I took the second table out and still same problem

Comment: Where are you setting the cell factory for the columns?

Comment: The cell factory is set right after the comment of where the columns get dynamically added                                                                           TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
                col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {

                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                    }

Comment: That's the cell value factory, not the cell factory. If you're not setting the cell factory, that's the problem...

Comment: Do you know any resources I could take a look at to do that? Is setting the cell factory using a separate class to set the Simple strings? This is where a lot of my confusion lies

Comment: I just figured it all out from the [standard tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) and digging through the Javadocs. A lot of people seem to like [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/)

Comment: __never-ever__ have a setter for the _property_ - instead have a setter for its value

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting a [`cellFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellFactoryProperty) on the table columns. The default cell factory provides a cell that does not support editing (essentially the cell is just a label). You need

```
col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

which will provide a `TextField`-based editing cell for the columns.

To get the `ObservableList<ObservableList>` to update, since your table doesn't use the standard JavaFX property patterns, you will also need to register a handler for edit commits:

```
col.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
    ObservableList row = e.getRowValue();
    row.set(j, e.getNewValue());
});
```

Note that you are using a whole bunch of raw types in your code, for which you should be getting a whole slew of warnings from the compiler. You might need to fix these to use the correct type in order to get the code above to compile. (E.g. you should have `TableView<ObservableList<String>>`, `TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>`, etc etc.)

Comment: I updated the code and studied the tutorial a bit, but still get thrown off by this after adding in the setOnEditComit code: its saying that it cannot find the symbol getRowValue and getNewValue